# Proper normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Definition: A subgroup $N$ is a proper normal subgroup of a group $G$ IFF
$Ng=gN \; \; \forall g \in G$

A proper normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ that is not the whole of $G$.
Wouldn't this implies that there is at least one element $g$ in $G$ that is not in $N$?
If so, doesn't this contradicts the definition of a normal subgroup?

Clarification is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would it contradict anything? Did you try some small examples, such as with $N$ being the trivial subgroup, or $G$ being some small abelian group?

Comment: Note that what you cite as Definition of *proper normal* subgroup in the first line, is in fact the definition of just *normal* subgroup. Therefore I added short forms of all relevant definitions in my answer ...

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a group.

A **subgroup** $H$ is a subset of $G$ that is also a group (under the same operation). Notation: $H\le G$. For example, we always have $G\le G$ and we always have $1\le G$ (where $1$ denotes the trivial subgroup of $G$ consisting only of its neutral element).

A **proper subgroup** of $G$ is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $H\ne G$. Notation: $H<G$.

A **normal subgroup** is a subgroup $N\le G$ such that $\forall g\in G\colon gN=Ng$. Notation: $N\trianglelefteq G$. Note that we always have $G\trianglelefteq G$ and $1\trianglelefteq G$

A **proper normal subgroup** is a normal subgroup that is also a proper subgroup. Notation: $N\lhd G$. From the above examples, we see that at least for non-trivial groups $G$, there always axists at least on proper normal subgroup (namely the trivial subgroup).

(Actually, there is a similar possible cause of confusion as with e.g. $\subset$, where some authors use $\subseteq/\subset$ and others use $\subset/\subsetneq$)

Comment: While this is all correct, it does not actually seem to answer the specific question posed, namely how being proper does not contradict being normal.